# CSS Minifier that doesn't just strip whitespace?

Tags: css

Almost all the CSS minifiers I can find are basically regexes that strip whitespace. Are there any CSS minifiers that are a little smarter about it? like merging selectors/properties that are similar, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Google stuff like "CSS optimizer" or "CSS cleaner". I found that [Clean CSS](http://www.cleancss.com/) did the job pretty well!